# Exporting NDVI CSV data of a rectangular region

Tags: export, csv, modis, ndvi

I am using the MODIS MOD13Q1 NDVI in the Google Earth Engine for my thesis project. I created a rectangular region to export CSV data. But I am having trouble exporting the NDVI data associated with the timespan that I am looking at. This is my code so far (the only thing that's not being exported is the NDVI data):

```js
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2000-03-01', '2020-06-01'));
var ndvi = dataset.select('NDVI');
var ndviVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 8000.0,
  palette: [
    'FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718', '74A901',
    '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201', '004C00', '023B01',
    '012E01', '011D01', '011301'
  ],
};
Map.setCenter(30.12884910803246,7.396618943073097);
Map.addLayer(ndvi, ndviVis, 'NDVI');

var rectangle = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([-31.27142723303246, -30.12884910803246,31.27142723303246, 30.12884910803246]);

// Make a collection of points.
var features = ee.FeatureCollection([
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(31.27142723303246,7.396618943073097), {name: 'Ironman'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(31.27142723303246,9.591374979848126), {name: 'Cpt. America'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(30.12884910803246,9.591374979848126), {name: 'Thor'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(30.12884910803246,7.396618943073097), {name: 'Thanos'}),
]);

// Export the FeatureCollection to a CSV file.
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: ndvi,
  description:'dataToDriveExample',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```